# Arduino NFC Module (DFRobot) not reading Whiztags

Tags: arduino, tags, nfc, arduino-uno, uart

I bought the [NFC module from DFRobot](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/NFC_Module_for_Arduino_(SKU:DFR0231)) and I'm using their example program with some changes since I only want to read the UID of my tag. It works great with the tag that came with it but it doesn't recognize any of my [NFC Whiztags](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FS4AF0S) (which contain a Topaz 512 chip).

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/* 

 # Editor : Adrian
 # Date   : 2013.04.18
 # Ver    : 0.1
 # Product: NFC Module for Arduino
 # SKU    : DFR0231

 # Description:     
 # When the a card close to the device , the PC will receive the data 
 # Connect the NFC Card's TXD, RXD, GND, +3.3V to Nano's D0RX, D1TX, GND, +3.3V
 # Or connect the NFC Card's TXD, RXD, GND, +5V to Nano's D0RX, D1TX, GND, +5V


 PN532 reads the tag by Arduino mega/Leonardo
 command list:

 #wake up reader
 send: 55 55 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 03 fd d4 14 01 17 00
 return: 00 00 FF 00 FF 00 00 00 FF 02 FE D5 15 16 00

 #get firmware
 send: 00 00 FF 02 FE D4 02 2A 00
 return: 00 00 FF 00 FF 00 00 00 FF 06 FA D5 03 32 01 06 07 E8 00

 #read the tag
 send: 00 00 FF 04 FC D4 4A 01 00 E1 00
 return: 00 00 FF 00 FF 00 00 00 FF 0C F4 D5 4B 01 01 00 04 08 04 XX XX XX XX 5A 00
 XX is tag.

 */

 //************* start **************

const unsigned char wake[24]={
  0x55, 0x55, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, \
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x03, 0xfd, 0xd4, 0x14, 0x01, 0x17, 0x00};//wake up NFC module
const unsigned char firmware[9]={
  0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x02, 0xFE, 0xD4, 0x02, 0x2A, 0x00};//
const unsigned char tag[11]={
  0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x04, 0xFC, 0xD4, 0x4A, 0x01, 0x00, 0xE1, 0x00};//detecting tag command
const unsigned char std_ACK[25] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x0C, \
0xF4, 0xD5, 0x4B, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x04, 0x08, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4b, 0x00};
char old_id[5];

unsigned char receive_ACK[25];//Command receiving buffer
//int inByte = 0;               //incoming serial byte buffer

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#define print1Byte(args) mySerial.write(args)
#define print1lnByte(args)  mySerial.write(args),mySerial.println()
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#define print1Byte(args) mySerial.print(args,BYTE)
#define print1lnByte(args)  mySerial.println(args,BYTE)
#endif

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
unsigned char myUID[12] = "70 89 7E 43";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);   // open serial with PC
  mySerial.begin(115200);    //open mySerial with device
  wake_card();
  delay(200);
  Serial.println("Scanning..."); 

}

void loop()
{
  send_tag(); 
  read_ACK(25);
  delay(100);
      if (test_ACK ()) {
        copy_id ();
        displayuid ();
         delay (10000);
       }

    }


void copy_id (void) 
{//save old id
  int ai, oi;
  for (oi=0, ai=19; oi<5; oi++,ai++) {
    old_id[oi] = receive_ACK[ai];
  }
}

int test_ACK (void) 
{// return true if receive_ACK accord with std_ACK
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<19; i++) {
    if (receive_ACK[i] != std_ACK[i])
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}


void send_id (void) 
{//send id to PC
  int i;
  Serial.print ("ID: ");
  for (i=19; i<= 23; i++) {
    Serial.print (receive_ACK[i], HEX);
    Serial.print (" ");
  }
  Serial.println ();
}


void UART1_Send_Byte(unsigned char command_data)
{//send byte to device
  print1Byte(command_data);
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
  mySerial.flush();// complete the transmission of outgoing serial data 
#endif
} 


void UART_Send_Byte(unsigned char command_data)
{//send byte to PC
  Serial.print(command_data,HEX);
  Serial.print(" ");
} 


void read_ACK(unsigned char temp)
{//read ACK into receive_ACK[]
  unsigned char i;
  for(i=0;i<temp;i++) {
  receive_ACK[i]= mySerial.read();
  }
}

void wake_card(void)
{//send wake[] to device
  unsigned char i;
  for(i=0;i<24;i++) //send command
  UART1_Send_Byte(wake[i]);
}


void send_tag(void)
{//send tag[] to device
  unsigned char i;
  for(i=0;i<11;i++) //send command
  UART1_Send_Byte(tag[i]);
}


void displayuid(void)
{//send receive_ACK[] to PC
  unsigned char i;
  for(i=0;i<4;i++) //send command
  UART_Send_Byte(old_id[i]);
  Serial.println();
}


//*********** end *************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reader module contains an NXP PN532 NFC transmission module IC. You currently use the following command to poll for tags:

```
tag = { 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x04, 0xFC, 0xD4, 0x4A, 0x01, 0x00, 0xE1, 0x00};
```

This command is an InListPassiveTarget command (command code `D4 4A`) with the parameters

- maximum number of initialized tags (MaxTg) = 1 (`0x01`) and
- tag protocol type (BrTy) = ISO/IEC 14443A at 106 kbps (`0x00`).

Hence, you can only detect tags that speak the full type A protocol defined in ISO/IEC 14443-3 (including anti-collision). Such tags are, for instance,

- NFC Forum Type 2 tags,
- NFC Forum Type 4 tags using the Type A protocol variant,
- NXP MIFARE Ultralight / Classic / DESFire / NTAG,
- NXP NTAG,
- Infineon my-D,
- Kovio 2K,
- and possibly others.

The Whiztags contain a Topaz 512 chip (which is an NFC Forum Type 1 tag). This tag type only partially implements ISO/IEC 14443 Type A (anti-collision mechanism not supported). Consequently, the above polling command won't enumerate such tags. Instead, you would need to switch the BrTy parameter to "Innovision Jewel tag at 106 kbps" (`0x04`). The modified command (including the update checksum byte) would look like this:

```
tag = { 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x04, 0xFC, 0xD4, 0x4A, 0x01, 0x04, 0xDD, 0x00};
```

You can find further details in the [PN532 user manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/141520.pdf).